# Simplifying database structure with many unequal vectors

Tags: mysql, database-design, json

I want to find an efficient way to represent the JSON objects below. I made an ERD diagram to represents the JSON objects. This diagram below is a small piece within a much larger structure. There will be at most 10 thousand rows in the main table (`InteractiveGraphOptions`), so it will not be a huge one.

My questions are:

1. Is there a way to represent vectors in MySQL other than an individual table?

   Let me give the example of `LineSegments`. Within an interactive graph, there might be many line segments and each line segment is represented by x and y coordinates. For example, there can be three line segments with coordinates  `{[(-4, 3.5) (4, -0.5)], [(-5, 6.5) (4.5, 9)], [(-5, -5) (5, -5)]}`, each point represents the beginning and end of a line segment and the order of the line segments is important (i.e. `{[(-5, 6.5) (4.5, 9)], [(-4, 3.5) (4, -0.5)], [(-5, -5) (5, -5)]}` should represent a different set of line segments). To represent these line segments, I created a new table with columns `x`, `y`, and `coordOrder`. So, I'll represent the three line segments above with 6 rows. Is there another way to save coordinates in MySQL reliably? Technically, I can save it as a string object and decompose it programmatically. But this method sounds somewhat prone to error.
2. My second question is similar to the one above. Whenever I see a vector that has a fixed size I decompose it as columns. Is there a way to save vectors with fixed length?

   For example, `labels` is the label of the coordinate axes (generally a vector `["x", "y"]`). Since all coordinates used here are two dimensional, it's size is fixed. My solution to this is to create two columns `label_x` and `label_y`  in the main table (`InteractiveGraphOptions`). Is this the most sane method? Are there any other methods to save this `labels` variable into database?

   {"labels": [
          "x",
          "y"
      ] 
   }
3. Related to the previous questions, is there any way to simplify the database structure below?

[image]

JSON object:

```
{
    "markings": "graph",                    
    "showProtractor": true,
    "showRuler": false,
    "showTooltips": false,
    "rulerLabel": "",
    "rulerTicks": 10,
    "step": [
        1,
        1
    ],
    "backgroundImage": {
        "url": null
    },
    "labels": [
        "x",
        "y"
    ],
    "range": [
        [
            -10,
            10
        ],
        [
            -10,
            10
        ]
    ],
    "gridStep": [
        1,
        1
    ],
    "snapStep": [
        0.5,
        0.5
    ],
    "graph": {
        "type": "polygon",
        "numSides": 5,
        "snapTo": "grid"
    },
    "correct": {
        "type": "polygon",
        "coords": [
            [
                5.5,
                -8
            ],
            [
                4,
                1
            ],
            [
                -4,
                -4.5
            ],
            [
                -6,
                8
            ],
            [
                -7.5,
                -7
            ]
        ],
        "numSides": 5,
        "snapTo": "grid"
    }
}


{
    "markings": "graph",
    "showProtractor": false,
    "showRuler": false,
    "showTooltips": true,
    "rulerLabel": "",
    "rulerTicks": 10,
    "step": [
        1,
        1
    ],
    "backgroundImage": {
        "url": null
    },
    "labels": [
        "x",
        "y"
    ],
    "range": [
        [
            -10,
            10
        ],
        [
            -10,
            10
        ]
    ],
    "gridStep": [
        1,
        1
    ],
    "snapStep": [
        0.5,
        0.5
    ],
    "graph": {
        "type": "quadratic"
    },
    "correct": {
        "type": "quadratic",
        "coords": [
            [
                -6,
                2.5
            ],
            [
                1.5,
                1
            ],
            [
                5,
                5
            ]
        ]
    }
}


{
    "markings": "grid",
    "showProtractor": false,
    "showRuler": true,
    "showTooltips": false,
    "rulerLabel": "",
    "rulerTicks": 10,
    "step": [
        1,
        1
    ],
    "backgroundImage": {
        "url": null
    },
    "labels": [
        "x",
        "y"
    ],
    "range": [
        [
            -10,
            10
        ],
        [
            -10,
            10
        ]
    ],
    "gridStep": [
        1,
        1
    ],
    "snapStep": [
        0.5,
        0.5
    ],
    "graph": {
        "type": "angle",
        "showAngles": true
    },
    "correct": {
        "type": "angle",
        "coords": [
            [
                0.8581143926302237,
                -0.6058011676632082
            ],
            [
                0,
                5.5
            ],
            [
                -7.245121074324528,
                5.753005202976288
            ]
        ],
        "showAngles": true,
        "match": "congruent"
    }
}


{
    "type": "interactive-graph",
    "alignment": "default",
    "static": false,
    "graded": true,
    "options": {
        "step": [
            1,
            1
        ],
        "backgroundImage": {
            "url": null
        },
        "markings": "graph",
        "labels": [
            "x",
            "y"
        ],
        "showProtractor": false,
        "showRuler": false,
        "showTooltips": false,
        "rulerLabel": "",
        "rulerTicks": 10,
        "range": [
            [
                -10,
                10
            ],
            [
                -10,
                10
            ]
        ],
        "graph": {
            "type": "circle"
        },
        "correct": {
            "type": "circle",
            "center": [
                -1.5,
                2
            ],
            "radius": 5
        }
    }
}


{
    "type": "interactive-graph",
    "alignment": "default",
    "static": false,
    "graded": true,
    "options": {
        "step": [
            1,
            1
        ],
        "backgroundImage": {
            "url": null
        },
        "markings": "graph",
        "labels": [
            "x",
            "y"
        ],
        "showProtractor": false,
        "showRuler": false,
        "showTooltips": false,
        "rulerLabel": "",
        "rulerTicks": 10,
        "range": [
            [
                -10,
                10
            ],
            [
                -10,
                10
            ]
        ],
        "graph": {
            "type": "ray"
        },
        "correct": {
            "type": "ray",
            "coords": [
                [
                    5.5,
                    -2.5
                ],
                [
                    -4.5,
                    5
                ]
            ]
        }
    }
}

{
    "type": "interactive-graph",
    "alignment": "default",
    "static": false,
    "graded": true,
    "options": {
        "step": [
            1,
            1
        ],
        "backgroundImage": {
            "url": null
        },
        "markings": "graph",
        "labels": [
            "x",
            "y"
        ],
        "showProtractor": false,
        "showRuler": false,
        "showTooltips": false,
        "rulerLabel": "",
        "rulerTicks": 10,
        "range": [
            [
                -10,
                10
            ],
            [
                -10,
                10
            ]
        ],
        "graph": {
            "type": "sinusoid"
        },
        "correct": {
            "type": "sinusoid",
            "coords": [
                [
                    0.5,
                    -2
                ],
                [
                    4.5,
                    3.5
                ]
            ]
        }
    }
}


{
    "type": "interactive-graph",
    "alignment": "default",
    "static": false,
    "graded": true,
    "options": {
        "step": [
            1,
            1
        ],
        "backgroundImage": {
            "url": null
        },
        "markings": "graph",
        "labels": [
            "x",
            "y"
        ],
        "showProtractor": false,
        "showRuler": false,
        "showTooltips": false,
        "rulerLabel": "",
        "rulerTicks": 10,
        "range": [
            [
                -10,
                10
            ],
            [
                -10,
                10
            ]
        ],
        "graph": {
            "type": "segment",
            "numSegments": 4
        },
        "correct": {
            "type": "segment",
            "numSegments": 4,
            "coords": [
                [
                    [
                        0.5,
                        -7.5
                    ],
                    [
                        6,
                        9
                    ]
                ],
                [
                    [
                        -5.5,
                        -9
                    ],
                    [
                        5,
                        2
                    ]
                ],
                [
                    [
                        -8,
                        -2.5
                    ],
                    [
                        -7,
                        -7
                    ]
                ],
                [
                    [
                        5.5,
                        -7.5
                    ],
                    [
                        7.5,
                        -5
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

When building an assessment test, these parameters will be send to the [plugin here](https://khan.github.io/perseus/#content=%7B%22question%22%3A%7B%22content%22%3A%22Please%20show%20the%20line%20corresponding%20to%20the%20equation%20%24y%20%3D%20x%20%2B%202%24.%5Cn%5Cn%5B%5B%E2%98%83%20interactive-graph%201%5D%5D%5Cn%5Cn%22%2C%22images%22%3A%7B%7D%2C%22widgets%22%3A%7B%22interactive-graph%201%22%3A%7B%22type%22%3A%22interactive-graph%22%2C%22alignment%22%3A%22default%22%2C%22static%22%3Afalse%2C%22graded%22%3Atrue%2C%22options%22%3A%7B%22step%22%3A%5B1%2C1%5D%2C%22backgroundImage%22%3A%7B%22url%22%3Anull%7D%2C%22markings%22%3A%22graph%22%2C%22labels%22%3A%5B%22x%22%2C%22y%22%5D%2C%22showProtractor%22%3Afalse%2C%22showRuler%22%3Afalse%2C%22showTooltips%22%3Afalse%2C%22rulerLabel%22%3A%22%22%2C%22rulerTicks%22%3A10%2C%22range%22%3A%5B%5B-5%2C5%5D%2C%5B-5%2C5%5D%5D%2C%22gridStep%22%3A%5B0.5%2C0.5%5D%2C%22snapStep%22%3A%5B0.5%2C0.5%5D%2C%22graph%22%3A%7B%22type%22%3A%22linear%22%7D%2C%22correct%22%3A%7B%22type%22%3A%22linear%22%2C%22coords%22%3A%5B%5B-2%2C0%5D%2C%5B0%2C2%5D%5D%7D%7D%2C%22version%22%3A%7B%22major%22%3A0%2C%22minor%22%3A0%7D%7D%7D%7D%2C%22answerArea%22%3A%7B%22calculator%22%3Afalse%2C%22chi2Table%22%3Afalse%2C%22periodicTable%22%3Afalse%2C%22tTable%22%3Afalse%2C%22zTable%22%3Afalse%7D%2C%22itemDataVersion%22%3A%7B%22major%22%3A0%2C%22minor%22%3A1%7D%2C%22hints%22%3A%5B%5D%7D) to construct a question. Later, student response from the plugin will be compared to the `Coordinates` in the database to determine whether the response is correct or not.

Comment: How is this data going to be searched?

Comment: The database model shown above will be a part of a larger `AssessmentQuestion` model. I've edited my question above to describe how it will be used at the end. (The plugin link was long and comment did not allow me to insert it).

Comment: Will the math be done in SQL?  Or in some app language?  Or the plugin?  If the plugin, what structure does it require?

Comment: ​​Math will be done in Python, for example, summarizing common mistakes​ or checking whether an answer is correct​. Some part of it will​/may​ be done by the plug-in, like checking whether an answer is correct​ but I haven't figured out how to do that using plugin yet. ​